# Android Volley- How to send raw text and get json response

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am new to android and using volley to communicate with web services.
[Postman details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ELLU.png)

I found sending a raw text to the web service will only work on postman.I try using grant_type=password&username=myusername&password=mypassowrd getting myusername and mypassword from two editText from my mainActivity, .
Is there any better way to achieve this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnLogin,btnFetch,btnExit;
EditText editTxtUsr,editTxtPass;
TextView txtView;
String uRL ="****";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnLogin=findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    btnFetch=findViewById(R.id.buttonFetch);
    btnExit=findViewById(R.id.buttonExit);
    editTxtUsr=findViewById(R.id.editTextUsrname);
    editTxtPass=findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    txtView=findViewById(R.id.textViewData);


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String wsURL = uRL + "/authtoken";
            //final String appData = "grant_type=password&username=" + editTxtUsr + "&password=" + editTxtPass;

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, wsURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.equals("true")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some error occured" + volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String,String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/text");
                    headers.put("charset", "TYPE_UTF8_CHARSET");
                    return headers;

                }

                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                    parameters.put("grand_type", "SET_VALUE");
                    parameters.put("Username", editTxtUsr.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("Password", editTxtPass.getText().toString());
                    return parameters;

                }
            };

            RequestQueue rQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            rQueue.add(request);
        }
    });

    btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I have tried various ways to achieve this, but with no luck. That's a sample of my code that I use to try to connect to the web service.

I get  [253] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for...

I searched thoroughly through StackOverflow but I can't seem to find the correct answer to my question.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been days I have been working on this but after I posted my question, I found the solution after some tries.
The answer is simpler than I have thought.
What you need to do is make an objectrequest and override the body with the text you want to post. Nothing had to change in headers or parameters.
I still can't find an answer using Stringrequest.

```
                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() {
                    try {
                        return requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                }
```

Where requestBody is the raw text you want to send as a string.